# wooCommerce event / hook when changing billing_country

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

If I change a country as a user, for example from Belgium to Belau. I see the state/county field appearing. In Belgium, you don't have states, so this is good that WooCommerce doesn't show this field if you have selected Belgium.

If I try to write a plugin that makes use of `add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_function' );`, this filter is not reloaded after a user changed the selected country.

You can listen to it through jQuery like `$('select#billing_country').change`, but then you get a hacky solution where you have to wait for an unknown time and then trigger a reload page.

So my question is: What is the best approach to customize checkout fields, for multiple countries, where the user can switch between countries?

Thanks, regards, Peter

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me explain a little bit more about why I think it feels 'hacky'. So without plugins: when I change it, fields change in front-end by default from WooCommerce. There are no filters (that I have found) that WooCommerce does change things the way I want (for Belgium this, for Netherlands that..). So then I have to do some things in front-end as well, and then you get the situation of race condition where apparatly multiple scripts try to change fields.

Comment: I found 'country_to_state_changing' is a good/nice trigger I can use for this. Any ideas to improve on that?

Comment: It could be hacky, especially depending on what needs to be changed on the page when a user changes their billing/shipping info.  If you are offering a discount on shipping or excise tax, for instance, JS can be easily manipulated by customers.  They could start with Belgium, get a discount, delete the JS lines, switch countries, and they still have the discount.

Did you ever resolve this?